# XeLaTex error with using TECkit mapping (RomDev for Roman to Devanagari script)

Tags: xetex, fontspec, indic

I'm attempting to typeset Devanagari in XeLaTeX. I'm using the font chandas.ttf and the RomDev mapping (for roman --> devanagari script; found here: [RomDev from somadeva](https://github.com/somadeva/RomDev)). This worked for me once upon a time. But now when I compile, I only get output in Roman script and an error message:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist-latn"
* 
* Font 'Chandas' does not contain script 'Devanagari'.
* 'Latin' script used instead.
*************************************************
```

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=RomDev]{Chandas}
\setmainlanguage{sanskrit}


\begin{document}

śarvavarmā tataścedamadbhutaṃ vākyamabravīt || śrutimantaṃ me kurviti   prāguktaṃ deva me tvayā |  

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have experienced the same warning message for Tamil and Sanskrit scripts, but the compilation proceeds correctly nevertheless. I have posted my MWE here: http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2016-September/026824.html

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded and installed [chandas.ttf from its website](http://www.sanskritweb.net/cakram/), and compiled the above file. It produced output looking like this:

[image: output without RomDev]

but without the fontspec warning that you see (which is anyway irrelevant and not related to your issue, despite appearing related). There's nothing in the shell output, but buried somewhere in the `.log` file is this:

```
Font mapping `RomDev.tec' for font `Chandas' not found.
```

Well, duh. So I downloaded [RomDev.map](https://github.com/somadeva/RomDev) ([here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/somadeva/RomDev/master/RomDev.map)), moved it into the same directory, and ran

> teckit_compile RomDev.map -o RomDev.tec

Now with `RomDev.tec` present in the same directory, compiling the file again with XeLaTeX gives output that looks like this, as desired:

[image: With RomDev]

Problem solved.

There are [ways](http://cikitsa.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-do-i-install-romdev-mapping-for.html) to make it work without `RomDev.tec` being in the same directory; you can pursue those if interested.